# Egit equivalent of "git push -f origin master:staging"

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

What would i have to do in eclipse Egit in order to perform the equivalent of the console command:

```
git push -f origin master:staging
```

which will push my local master branch to the remote staging branch, overriding all remote changes. Ideally, this should be a one-time command which does not change any push settings on Egit permanently.

Comment: You can't do that in the egit push wizard ? when selecting source and destination, and checking the force checkbox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As flafoux pointed out correctly, this is how it works:

[image: Rightklick on Project -> TEam -> Remote -> Push...]

[image: Presse Next -> Enter refs -> Add Spec -> Force Update -> Finish]